# MySQL Update Statement: Unknown 'table' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

As soon as I am trying to use `UPDATE`, following error appears as soon as I hit GO:

> ## 1109 - Unkown table 'user' in 'field list'

Now since I knew that this table name is not the best and unique that has been used, I tried to get a little more specific with my statement:

```
UPDATE
    MyDatabase.user
SET
    MyDatabase.user.registeredAt = NOW()
WHERE
    MyDatabase.user.id = 3;
```

Still the same error. I tried it with a ` around the table or with the statement phpmyadmin builds for you on one button push but still the same.
Since changing the name is not an option, even though I know it's bad, there is no other option than trying to get him find that table.

What am I missing?

Information about php and mySql:

- PHP-Version: 5.6.38
- Database-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11
- Server-Version: 10.1.36-MariaDB

---

EDIT
I have read about a bug when mySQL haven't been installed correctly, this error occurs more often. Since I've installed the whole package with XAMPP, there could be no possibility of this bug, isn't it?

Comment: @madhurbhaiya what difference would that make?

Comment: It isn't, so it won't

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes I tried to wrap the table name and the column with backticks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a table named user in your db MyDatabase ??

Comment: @scaisEdge Im very sure the table exists. I can see it, Drop it, Select or other statements work and the login from the website works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have a table named like that:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'MyDatabase' and table_name = 'user';
```

---

`user´ is a reserved keyword, so you need to quote your table name with backticks.

```
UPDATE
    MyDatabase.`user`
SET
    MyDatabase.`user`.registeredAt = NOW()
WHERE
    MyDatabase.`user`.id = 3;
```

When your database name also needs quoting, do not include both database name and table name.

This is wrong:

```
`databasename.tablename`
```

This is right:

```
`databasename`.`tablename`
```

Comment: Interesting, could have sworn I tried it wiith ` wrapped around the table. But it works, thats what matters and I learned a new statement to check if the table exists.