# Table gets unknown to database when adding trigger

Tags: mysql, xampp, database-trigger

As soon as I am adding a after update trigger to my user table, the table gets unknown to the database.

> ## 1109 - Unbekannte Tabelle 'k25831_dotlan.user' in 'field list'

The Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_UpdateNewsletterDate` 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW 
IF k25831_dotlan.`user`.newsletter = 1 AND k25831_dotlan.`user`.newsletterdate IS NULL 
THEN 
BEGIN 
UPDATE k25831_dotlan.`user` SET k25831_dotlan.`user`.newsletterdate = NOW() WHERE k25831_dotlan.`user`.id = k25831_dotlan.`user`.id; 
END; 
END IF
```

As I found out in my simillar question [MySQL Update Statement: Unknown 'table' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842026/mysql-update-statement-unknown-table-in-field-list) that without the trigger, there is no problem to have a table called user. As soon as I drop the trigger, updates and any other queries are working as intended.

Information about php and mySql:

- PHP-Version: 5.6.38
- Database-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11
- Server-Version: 10.1.36-MariaDB

The install process has been taken over by xampp.

Comment: Your syntax looks wrong. Please edit your question to add complete Trigger code.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Im sorry, thought the body is enough.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for the hint with OLD and NEW, im new to working with triggers and didn't read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Begin` comes at the start of the body of the trigger. Afterwards, all the other conditional statements/queries/variable assignment etc will come.

**By the way, what does your Trigger do. Without accessing `OLD` and `NEW`, it does not make any sense**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_UpdateNewsletterDate` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `k25831_dotlan`.`user` 
FOR EACH ROW  
  BEGIN 

    IF `k25831_dotlan`.`user`.`newsletter` = 1 AND 
       `k25831_dotlan`.`user`.`newsletterdate` IS NULL THEN

      UPDATE `k25831_dotlan`.`user` 
      SET `k25831_dotlan`.`user`.`newsletterdate` = NOW() 
      WHERE `k25831_dotlan`.`user`.`id` = `k25831_dotlan`.`user`.`id`;
    END IF; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```